stat not giving birth datetime in cluster
with the command
stat file.txt I get
Access: 2024-06-10 14:55:36.254879000 +0300
Modify: 2024-06-10 14:55:36.254879000 +0300
Change: 2024-06-10 14:55:36.254879000 +0300
Birth: -

I work in a cluster thus I am not a sudo and I can't execute any sudo command. Note that the OS is very old (as you can see) thus statx can't work for me.
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)
Release:        7.9.2009
Codename:       Core

Thus, I would like to ask if there is any way to view the birth time.
Thanks

Please edit your question to indicate what filesystem is used on the cluster.

Does this answer your question? How can get the creation date of a file?

@AdminBee hello, my friend unfortunately no. Indeed, it is one of the questions I viewed before asking my question. Thanks.

If stat can't read the birth time, it's either not stored in the file system at all (that is normal for many file systems!), or your old kernel's stat simply doesn't know where to get it. Check with your administrator that you are not trying to get data that simply never got stored!

Note that the OS is very old (as you can see) thus statx can't work for me

yep, centOS (and RHEL) 7.9 should have only Linux 3.10, and that increases the likelihood of your system using a file system that doesn't even store the birth time. (RHEL admins are typically concerned with reliability, and hence tend to choose their file systems conservatively. Try df -h -T to see whether your system tells you the type of your file system. XFS, for example, prior to 2020 simply didn't have the field, nor, if I remember correctly, did ext3, or ReiserFS).
In fact, as said in the answer you've been linked to, you simply have no way of asking the kernel for this information as user. You're out of luck – you need someone with access to debugfs (i.e., root privileges) to ask your kernel.
Edit: now in the comment you mention this file system is NFS.
You will need NFSv4 to transport the birth date file attribute at all (you probably are using that) and a kernel at least 5.17, which CentOS 7.9 does not have.
So, what you want is impossible on your platform. Nothing is getting the birth date from the NFS data and presenting it to userland.

AFAICT birth time was added to XFS in Linux in 2013.

@StéphaneChazelas I thought that was an XFS v5 thing? And that came with Linux 4.2 (????? I think), and hence wouldn't be in RHEL 7

Sorry, that commit was when fields were reserved in the inode, I'll dig for the commit where that's actually functional.

Actually looks like that was functional, but there may not have been an API to retrieve it. V5 might have been when you could retrieve it with statx().

@MarcusMüller     Filesystem   Type  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
......................    nfs    ...................................................................
(i have replaced the real parameters with dots)

@DimitrisTsiaousidis see my edit.

@MarcusMüller thank you very much.
CentOS Linux 7 end of life is June 30, 2024, thus they will replace it in the upcoming weeks with Rocky Linux 9. I hope that the new one has more capabilities.
